# What is my API key in debug mode

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I understand that in order to use google maps I need to have the following in my manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

and I need to replace YOUR_API_KEY with my real API Key. I am also aware that my real API key will be one thing for my released app and something else for my development version in debug mode.

Just for now I'd be happy enough to get it working in debug mode, but unfortunately I can not understand the google documentation well enough to work out what my debug mode API key actually is! Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short and explanatory guide for generating your own `Google Maps API Key for Android` that I wrote. Take a look at this and see if this is more clear for:

[Google Maps API V2 key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

If you have any questions you are welcome to ask.

In short you have to get your `SHA1` fingerprint using the `keytool` included with your `JDK` installation.

Register this `SHA1` fingerprint with your application package in `Google API Console` and this will produce a `Google API Key` for your application.